# Noise/distortion after doing filters with vDSP_deq22 (biquad IIR filter)

Tags: c++, objective-c, signal-processing, accelerate-framework, vdsp

I'm working on a DSP class (obj-c++) for [Novocaine](http://alexbw.github.com/novocaine/), but my filters only seem to cause noise/distortion on the signal.

I've posted my full code and coefficients here: https://gist.github.com/2702844
But it basically boils down to:

```
// Deinterleaving...
// DSP'ing one channel:
NVDSP *handleDSP = [[NVDSP alloc] init];
[handleDSP setSamplingRate:audioManager.samplingRate];
float cornerFrequency = 6000.0f;
float Q = 0.5f;
[handleDSP setHPF:cornerFrequency Q:Q];
[handleDSP applyFilter:audioData length:numFrames];

// DSP other channel in the same way
// Interleaving and sending to audio output (Novocaine block)
```

See the gist for full code/context.

The coefficients:

```
2012-05-15 17:54:18.858 nvdsp[700:16703] b0: 0.472029
2012-05-15 17:54:18.859 nvdsp[700:16703] b1: -0.944059
2012-05-15 17:54:18.860 nvdsp[700:16703] b2: 0.472029
2012-05-15 17:54:18.861 nvdsp[700:16703] a1: -0.748175
2012-05-15 17:54:18.861 nvdsp[700:16703] a2: 0.139942
```

(all divided by `a0`)

Since I presumed the coefficients are in the order of: `{ b0/a0, b1/a0, b2/a0, a1/a0, a2/a0 }` (see: [IIR coefficients for peaking EQ, how to pass them to vDSP_deq22?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10375359/iir-coefficients-for-peaking-eq-how-to-pass-them-to-vdsp-deq22))

What is causing the distortion/noise (the filters don't work)?

Comment: "Distortion/noise" isn't very descriptive.  Do you have some plots you can add to your post for some simple test waveforms?  (e.g. an impulse).  Also, in the previous question you referred to, I was guessing at which was `a` and which was `b` in your case.  It's also possible that the numbering is back to front.

Comment: This japanese website also states the order of the coefficients is `b0, b1, b2, a1, a2`: http://objective-audio.jp/2008/02/biquad-filter.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update:** I recommend everyone to use my DSP class I released on github: https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP It'll probably save you quite some work.

Got it working, woooo! Long live the japanese: http://objective-audio.jp/2008/02/biquad-filter.html

The applyFilter method had to be:

```
- (void) applyFilter: (float *)data frames:(NSUInteger)frames {
    /*
     The first two samples of data being passed to vDSP_deq22 have to be initialized from the previous call. So, you'd want to hold onto a float buffer and feed the tailing two samples after a vDSP_deq22 call back to the front of that array for the next time you call. (Alex Wiltschko)
     */

    // Thanks a lot to: http://objective-audio.jp/2008/02/biquad-filter.html

    // Provide buffer for processing
    float *tInputBuffer = (float*) malloc((frames + 2) * sizeof(float));
    float *tOutputBuffer = (float*) malloc((frames + 2) * sizeof(float));

    // Copy the data
    memcpy(tInputBuffer, gInputKeepBuffer, 2 * sizeof(float));
    memcpy(tOutputBuffer, gOutputKeepBuffer, 2 * sizeof(float));
    memcpy(&(tInputBuffer[2]), data, frames * sizeof(float));

    // Do the processing
    vDSP_deq22(tInputBuffer, 1, coefficients, tOutputBuffer, 1, frames);

    // Copy the data
    memcpy(data, tOutputBuffer, frames * sizeof(float));
    memcpy(gInputKeepBuffer, &(tInputBuffer[frames]), 2 * sizeof(float));
    memcpy(gOutputKeepBuffer, &(tOutputBuffer[frames]), 2 * sizeof(float));

    free(tInputBuffer);
    free(tOutputBuffer);
}
```

Full class: https://github.com/bartolsthoorn/NVDSP

Comment: And here's a version written in pure math without using the Accelerate framework: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34312682/reimplement-vdsp-deq22-for-biquad-iir-filter-by-hand/34336833. Thanks for NVDSP!

Answer (score 0):

Copy the data with:

```
memcpy(data, tOutputBuffer+2, frames * sizeof(float));
```

And it will work